# React Native android doesn't load images for APK

Tags: android, image, android-studio, react-native, apk

after a part of my react native project, images doesn't load at APK file. But images is loaded on android studio emulator. Is there any solution?
this is my ImageBackground component for example :

```
<ImageBackground source={require('./../img/wallets-bg.png')}></ImageBackground>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I know when you build the APK is running some image bundler task, and there is your problem. That will not support the dash "-". Change your png name to `walletsbg.png` in your assets folder and try to use like this (all small letters):

```
<ImageBackground source={require('./../img/walletsbg.png')}></ImageBackground>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work still. I use react native and my assets folder is empty.

Comment: you need to rename the png from your img folder, inside your react-native project.. which is the loaded path from the source.  `./../img/walletsbg.png`
I guess the `assets` folder was misleading a little, sorry for that :)